# Which approach is better when passing settings to an object?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I want to set initial values of fields in an object, using $config. Which approach is better in terms of cleaner and more maintainable code?
Also, I would like to add that object will be initialized in a factory and not directly by client.

**1. I pass $config to the object**

```
<?php
class UserGreeting {
  private $config;
  public function __construct($config){
      $this->config=$config;
  }

  public function greetings(){
    echo 'Hello, '.$this->config->get('username');
  }
}
?>
```

Pros:

- Easy to pass multiple parameters

Cons:

- The class is coupled with $config ( is it?). What I mean is that
  apart from particular $config interface and parameters naming
  conventions, I can't just plug this class into another program
  without introducing $config
- Client code doesn't have to know which parameters are used by the
  object, but that is more general thought

**2. I set fields manually outside the object**

```
<?php
class UserGreetingFactory{
   public function __construct($config){
     $this->config=$config;
   }
   public function getUserGreeting(){
     $userGreeting=new UserGreeting();
     $userGreeting->setUserName='John Doe';
     return $userGreeing;
   }
} 

class UserGreeting {
   private userName;
   public function setUserName($userName){
     $this->userName=$userName;
   }
   public function greetings(){
     echo "Hello, {$this->userName}";
   }
  }
?>
```

Pros:

- The class doesn't care where his parameters are coming from
- Can reuse easily
- Easier to test(is it?). I mean that I don't have to deal with setting
  up $config

Cons:

- Factory\Builder has to know which parameers to pass
- Lots of extra code for setters and passing parameters

Comment: Some heavy editing going on here, wow! Respect to editors. You practically rewrote the entire thing!

Comment: You already answered your question. It should be obvious that the factory solution is the more maintainable one. Just one sidenote: you do not need to provide setters but can ctor inject $username (unless its an optional value)

Comment: Thanks for helping with editing, I am first timer with highlighting! The reason why I don't pass it to constructor is that I need multiple values, single username is just for simplicity in example

Comment: @Boris well, pass pass multiple values then. Pass everything the object needs to be in a valid state through the ctor. If you find that this gives you a very long params list, check if you can group some of those params into objects. Move creation of those into the Factory and inject the objects instead.

Comment: But then I would have to init the parameters object by passing long constructor or setting fields, wouldn't I?

Comment: Check http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object. Another option would be to [create a Builder to decouple collecting of the userdata values and creating the actual object out of it.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2)

Comment: ffs @BorisMikhaylov. You broke my edit. I worked hard on that!

Answer (score 1):

First solution with ctor injection. But instead of a special config i would just pass the actual objects. In your case an `User` object.

```
<?php
class UserGreeting
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function greet()
    {
        printf('Hello, %s!',  $this->user->getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your idea's, I'd stick to a single variable. If you want to pass the variables per-method you'll have a lot of excessive code.

From an OOP point of view, you shouldn't put it in a single variable. An object has properties. An username is in fact a property so you should use it as property. That means that in PHP classes you'd need to make it a public variable and set the variables when you create the object.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is better because of dependency injection. This code will be easier to test and to maintain.
The third way is to use Visitor pattern to inject dependencies.

Comment: The second approach is using dependency injection as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static class with static methods.  In effect they are like CONSTS, but you can enforce all kinds of rules within the static config class - that they conform to an interface for example.

```
Config::getUserName();
```

That way if you are going to be faced with a family of config objects, you can be assured they all have at least an entry for each expected value - otherwise a warning is chucked.

Might depend on your situation of course, and I expect there are many situations where you would not want to do this - but I will offer it up all the same.

Comment: this will introduce lots of coupling and I am under the impression that the OP is trying to avoid that.